# $http.get returns zero on IOS emulation

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I want to make a webapp by using the Angular and Cordova frameworks. Now I have everything up and running, but  I want to fetch a json feed by the $http.get method. In my browser it fetches the json object perfectly, but on my emulated IOS it returns zero.

I read something about an update with Cordova 4.0, which tells me to update whitelist (Cordova plugin whitelist) with domains which I connect to, but it looks like I am missing something. My config.xml contains the following configurations:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
```

My index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/libs/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/application/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/navigation/navigation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/news/news.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/default.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://localhost/path-to-site">
</head>
<body ng-app="mk">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav></nav>
            <div class="view-animate-container">
                <ng-view class="view-animate"></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My homepage html is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="homeNewsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in homenewsitems track by $index">
        <a class="newsitem" ng-href="#/newsitem?id={{item.ID}}">
            <div class="newsimage" style="background-image: url('{{item.featured_image.source}}');"></div>
        <h2 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h2>

        <p class="meta">{{item.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy / hh:mm'}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
<a class="read-more" ng-click="loadMore(1)">Meer nieuws laden</a>
```

And my controller is as follows:

```
app.controller('homeNewsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://domain/wp-json/posts').then(function (response) {
        $scope.homenewsitems = response.data;
        console.log(response);
    }, function error(response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });

    $scope.count = 1;

    $scope.loadMore = function (counter) {
        $scope.count += counter;
        $http.get('http://domain/wp-json/posts?page=' +         $scope.count).then(function (response) {
            $scope.homenewsitems.push.apply($scope.homenewsitems,     response.data);
        }, function error(response) {
            alert(response.status)
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution in the App Transport Security plugin.

https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security. In the plugin.xml I can manage the hosts to connect to.

Comment: Note you need to have both the App Transport Security AND Content Security Policy meta tag set correctly.  It's possible to configure them at cross purposes so one will allow a connection only to have the other block it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a "connect-src" clause to your content security policy meta tag so it looks more like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://hostname.mysite.com">
```

And swap out http://hostname.mysite.com for your server / list of servers and use http/https according to how you connect to those servers.  If running on iOS 9 you may also need to configure App Transport Security in your project plist file if accessing non SSL secured servers.  I wrote a [blog post](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) on this with an example project that should help you.

Comment: Well, now I just have a "Refused to connect error" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive..

Comment: Well, what does your CSP meta tag now look like, and which hosts are you trying to get connected to using which protocols.  There will be some miscoonfiguration but you'd need to post detail to get it solved here.

Comment: I run the Rest Api locally, so I used your suggestion with the meta tag you privoded with my own settings.

I have edited the code above to the code I have running now.

Comment: Problem would be that you're using connect-src http://localhost/path-to-site - when running in Cordova, localhost is the phone so this would refer to a relative path inside the device and not work.  You should use your development machine's IP address in this situation and make sure that you can reach that from the device simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but even with a path to the production server doesn't work.. I think it's better to have a closer look at the policies, so I can understand better what's going on.

Thanks a lot anyway